# Slickgrid Add tabs dynamically

Tags: javascript, tabs, slickgrid

I am using Slickgrid and I want to create multiple grids in different tabs, but I am having the following error:

[image]

**My Scripts**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="examples.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/lib/firebugx.js"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/lib/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>


<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.autotooltips.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellrangedecorator.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellrangeselector.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellcopymanager.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellselectionmodel.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.editors.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.formatters.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.compositeeditor.js"></script>
```

**My Code**

```
$(function () {$("div#tabs").tabs();})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples, under 'Bootstrap, Dynamic Grids and Third Party component editors'.

There are examples for multi grids on a page, and for dynamically creating new tabs containing a grid.

Comment: I am following the example Dynamically created SlickGrid inside jQuery tabs and I am literally copying the code, but I cant make the tabs work and I dont know why.

Comment: What you need to do is start with the working SlickGrid example (ie. download the repo to your computer and run it there), and add one small part of your page to it at a time. It could be a conflict between libraries, duplicate IDs in the page, or something to do with the order in which scripts are referenced. At some point, the example will break, and you'll know the last change caused the problem. Or, it will work and you no longer have a problem! Sorry, but this is called 'system integration' and it's really painful to do.

Comment: In my case,

`<tabset>
            <tab heading="title1" id="tab1">
                <child-child></child-child>
            </tab>
  <tab heading="title2">
       <child-child></child-child>
     </tab>
        </tabset>`
and child-child looks like below.

`<div id="demo-child-container" class="container-fluid">
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions1" [gridOptions]="gridOptions1" [dataset]="dataset1" gridHeight="300" gridWidth="800"></angular-slickgrid></div>`
I see a thin horizontal line in tabs 1,2, instead of table. Please suggest.

Comment: sorry, same suggestion. you need to run the example locally, and then add one bit at a time. If you're using angular, then make sure you download the angular repo.